# What is the meaning of the word "Lived" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is the context for the word "lived"

I'm watching this mini-documentary on youtube, about the movie "The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo". In it, there is this makeup artist, who talks about creating the main character in the movie, called Lisbeth Salander, played by Rooney Mara. She's this sort of, punk/emo girl who is supposed to have this very specific style. She talks about how hard it was to achieve this, and how they managed to do it. This is an excerpt of the conversation:

> There's this guy that I really love, that I worked with for years off and on, and I know him as an acquaintance and our friend, and his name is Danillo Dixon, and he's probably like a bit older than I am, he's like, lived all over the world, and so when I brought I'm up to see Ann and David [Fincher the director of the movie] when they were talking about cutting Rooney's hair I was like: if this guy can't get it [meaning make her look authentic and like a real punk girl] no one's gonna get it, because he's definitely in the fashion business but he's so real and **lived** and knows the punk scene.

So what that the word lived mean here?

Merriam Webster def for "live"
: to have a life rich in experience
the boy who is mentally alert lives more in a day than a dull boy does in a month

Comment: I always thought the girl was played by Noomi Rapace. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are but I don't think I should write about it on this forum :)

Answer (score 1):

In my view this is not a standard use of "lived", unlike "lived all over the world" earlier in the quote.

I can only suppose that by "he's so real and lived" that the makeup artist means "experienced", or something similar to that, but that is not very clear.

Comment: I can see it being a shortened form of 'lived the punk scene and knows [it]'. To live [something] can mean to be completely and thoroughly immersed in that thing.

Comment: @Michael Harvey
 yes that is also a possible meaning here, butthe quoted wording seems an odd way of expressing that thought.

Comment: The text of the spoken conversation, as quoted, seems to have lots of conversational fillers (e.g. frequent use of 'like', 'when I brought I'm up to see Ann and David', and so on. Not prepared.

Comment: @Michael Harvey yes that is true, so an informal or not well-considered usage is very possible.

Comment: This is indeed an off-the-cuff conversation. They were asking her questions and she was answering them.